# Creating static library from multiple sources

Tags: c++, linux, makefile

I'm trying to create a Makefile that, among other things, outputs some library1.a, that I will reuse afterwards to create an executable. Now here's my dilemma: I want to make the this process generic, so that I don't have to edit the Makefile each time I add some files. Here's what I have in mind:

```
#Declare phony targets
.PHONY: all clean build_utils

#Compiler
CXX = g++

#Flags
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -Werror -pedantic -std=c++0x -O2

#Directories
OUTPUT_DIR = _output/linux
INTERMEDIATE_DIR = _intermediate/linux
UTILS_DIR = utils

all: $(OUTPUT_DIR)/libUtils.a

$(OUTPUT_DIR)/libUtils.a:
    ar rcs $@ $(INTERMEDIATE_DIR)/utils/$(patsubst %.cpp, %.o, $(wildcard $(UTILS_DIR)/ *.cpp))

#create .o files in %INTERMEDIATE_DIR/utils
build_utils: $(UTILS_DIR)/ *.cpp $(UTILS_DIR)/ *.h
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $^ -o ## What must be placed here? ##
```

So, basically, I want all the object files to be created in a temporary directory and then to be archived in `libUtils.a`, but I can't figure out how to ask the compiler to output multiple object files based on the input files. Basically, my standards impose that for each .cpp file, I should get an object file, but I'm not sure how to do this. I don't want to create a separate target for each .o file, because it's too messy.

Comment: While this is not directly answering your question, I'd recommend to look at cmake to do the Makefile generation for you. It seems to have the type of  automation that you would like to implement built in.

Comment: @jpe cmake seems much more sophisticated than doing it manually. I'd have to invest a few days in it, and now I'm in a big hurry to get this project compiled.

Comment: In CMake you could actually create a library from all files matching a specific pattern in about three or four lines, that are much clearer to read than a Makefile. Not that doing it "manually" in a Makefile is necessarily a bad idea, just don't be put of by CMake maybe looking complex and sophisticated - it provides a lot of nice features, but is not at all that difficult to get accustomed to.

Comment: @sonicwave Well, maybe it's a good idea to use it when you're part of a team of programmers and all of you are in the stage where you're trying to figure out what tools fit best for this particular implementation. On the other hand, when you're the only programmer in the team and everybody is wondering "why is it taking you so damn long to implement these 2 formulas that we wrote in 10 minutes", then you need to keep stuff really simple, and, yet, scalable. Yes, I could have spent half of week reading about cmake, but, on the other hand, I also need to write the code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after many hours of digging, here's what I've managed to come up with:

```
#Build object files
$(INTERMEDIATE_DIR)/$(UTILS_DIR)/%.o: $(UTILS_DIR)/%.cpp $(UTILS_DIR)/%.h
    mkdir -p $(INTERMEDIATE_DIR)/$(UTILS_DIR)
    $(CXX) $< $(LIBCXXFLAGS) -o $@

$(INTERMEDIATE_DIR)/$(FUNCTIONS_DIR)/%.o: $(FUNCTIONS_DIR)/%.cpp $(FUNCTIONS_DIR)/%.h
    mkdir -p $(INTERMEDIATE_DIR)/$(FUNCTIONS_DIR)
    $(CXX) $< $(LIBCXXFLAGS) -o $@


#create the library archives
$(OUTPUT_DIR)/libUtils.a: $(patsubst %.cpp, $(INTERMEDIATE_DIR)/%.o, $(wildcard $(UTILS_DIR)/ *.cpp))
    ar rcs $@ $^
$(OUTPUT_DIR)/libFunctions.a: $(patsubst %.cpp, $(INTERMEDIATE_DIR)/%.o, $(wildcard $(FUNCTIONS_DIR)/ *.cpp))
    ar rcs $@ $^

#Builds the libraries
libs: $(OUTPUT_DIR)/libUtils.a $(OUTPUT_DIR)/libFunctions.a

#Main target
all: libs
```

The nice part about it is that I don't have to edit it each time I add a file. I think it can be made even more abstract than this, by having a single generic target which builds the object files, but that seems a bit too much.

PS: Thanks [Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11274505/1174378) for giving me a good idea on what to use! :)

LE: It seems that it's very hard to convince SO to not try to do syntax highlighting. Not even the `<pre></pre>` tag helps when dealing with `/*`...

Answer (score 3):

You can use a wildcard rule like the following to compile each C++ source file separately:

```
%.o: %.cpp
     $(CXX) $< $(CXXFLAGS) $@
```

After adding `-c -o` at the end of your `CXXFLAGS`. Then capture the result of the `patsubst` expression somewhere, like:

```
OBJECTS = $(patsubst %.cpp, %.o, $(wildcard $(UTILS_DIR)/*.cpp))
```

... and have the `$(OUTPUT_DIR)/libUtils.a` rule depend upon `$(OBJECTS)`.

Comment: Hm... This looks a bit messy, given that I want my .o files to be generated in multiple directories...

Comment: @MihaiTodor, you should have mentioned in your question that you wanted multiple intermediate directories, not just `utils/`. Do you have multiple source directories, and want a corresponding directory in `INTERMEDIATE_DIR` for each one?

Comment: Yes, that is my goal. I managed to do it in a more "decent way", though. I learned a lot about Makefiles today and I am adding an answer with my solution.